# Saxon/C PHP apache process stuck in FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE when calling compileFromString

Tags: php, saxon-c

Tried on fresh ubuntu 16.04 (with both stock php 7.0 and ondrej php 7.4, stock and hwe kernel), as well as on fresh ubuntu 18.04 with stock php 7.4.

Later edit: also tested on 20.04, both stock and latest apache2 + php from ondrej ppa.

Installed Saxon 1.2.1 HE and compiled php module using official instructions, all went well, just a few compiler warnings. Apache starts happily, module is loaded and listed in phpinfo.

But he simplest test, when calling `compileFromString` leads to apache worker to block like this:

```
futex(0x7fdc97e01a00, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x7fdc97e01a68, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL
# stuck here forever
```

At this point, restarting apache leads to complaints because of the above stuck child:

```
[Thu Oct 01 10:35:02.712717 2020] [core:error] [pid 1021] AH00046: child process 1053 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
```

Attaching with gdb shows:

```
    #0  0x00007f26ea102376 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from target:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
    #1  0x00007f26e1c951e3 in ?? () from target:/usr/lib/libsaxonhec.so
    #2  0x0000000000000005 in ?? ()
    #3  0x0000000000000005 in ?? ()
    #4  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Comment: Hi, This looks related to the bug issue described here: https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/4420. A patched file of php7_saxon.cpp can be found here https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/4371

Comment: Indeed it is related to https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/4371, unfortunately the fix does not seem to be production grade. Feel free to add it as answer.